# Progress bar on scroll to the right - React - e-commerce product row

Tags: reactjs, scroll, progress-bar, e-commerce

I'm trying to make a progress bar that starts as the user scrolls to the right for a row of products for a sample e-commerce site. I've been getting a number of type errors to which I've made adjustments, but I'm now still getting the error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" for line 12.

Please could someone provide assistance so it will work? (fyi pardon this code, still a bit of a React newbie). Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import { taskData } from "./cdg-data";
import ProgressBar from './progress';

class CDG extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scrollPosition: 0
  }

  listenToScrollEvent = () => {
    const element = document.querySelector("CDG");
    element.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        element.calculateScrollDistance();
      });
    });
  }
  
  calculateScrollDistance = () => {
    const element = document.querySelector("CDG");
    const pixels = element.scrollLeft; // CURRENT number of pixels scrolled by the user

    const elementWidth = element.clientWidth; // width of just the element (no scrolling)
    const fullElementWidth = element.scrollWidth; // full total distance of the element (with scrolling)
  
    const totalScrollableDistance = fullElementWidth - elementWidth;
    const scrollPosition = Math.floor(pixels / totalScrollableDistance * 100) // gets the percentage that the user has scrolled
    
    element.setState({
      scrollPosition,
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenToScrollEvent();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
    <h2 className="cdg-title">THE COLLECTION</h2>
      <div className="CDG">
        {taskData.map(item => {
          return (
            <div className="image-container">
              <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
              <p className="title">{item.title}</p>
              <p className="price">{item.price}</p>
              </a>
                <img className="cdg-image" 
                  src={item.image} 
                  alt="Converse"
                />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="Progress">
        <ProgressBar scroll={this.state.scrollPosition + '%'}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default CDG;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final correct solution if anyone needs it:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { taskData } from "./cdg-data";
import ProgressBar from './progress';

class CDG extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scrollPosition: 0
  }

  listenToScrollEvent = () => {
    const element = document.querySelector(".CDG");
    element.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.calculateScrollDistance();
      });
    });
  }
  
  calculateScrollDistance = () => {
    const element = document.querySelector(".CDG");
    const pixels = element.scrollLeft; // CURRENT number of pixels scrolled by the user

    const elementWidth = element.clientWidth; // width of just the element (no scrolling)
    const fullElementWidth = element.scrollWidth; // full total distance of the element (with scrolling)
  
    const totalScrollableDistance = fullElementWidth - elementWidth;
    const scrollPosition = Math.floor(pixels / totalScrollableDistance * 100) // gets the percentage that the user has scrolled
    
    this.setState({
      scrollPosition,
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenToScrollEvent();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
    <h2 className="cdg-title">THE COLLECTION</h2>
      <div className="CDG">
        {taskData.map(item => {
          return (
            <div className="image-container">
              <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
              <p className="title">{item.title}</p>
              <p className="price">{item.price}</p>
              </a>
                <img className="cdg-image" 
                  src={item.image} 
                  alt="Converse"
                />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="Progress">
        <ProgressBar scroll={this.state.scrollPosition + '%'}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default CDG;
```

```css
import React from 'react';

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    const { scroll } = props;

    const containerStyles = {
        height: 5,
        width: '33%',
        backgroundColor: '#939191',
        margin: '0 auto 50px',
    }

    const fillerStyles = {
        height: '100%',
        width: `${scroll}`, // dependent on JavaScript scroll, not the percentage completed as in the example
        backgroundColor: '#A50209',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
    return (
        <div style={containerStyles}>
            <div style={fillerStyles}>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};


export default ProgressBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for querySelector is incorrect. Try prefixing with a `.` here since you are selecting by a class:

`const element = document.querySelector('.CDG')`

For future reference, MDN's docs on writing query selectors for different types of ID/selectors/tags

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector